# Finding minimum height of binary tree...code missing 1 minor edit to pass all test cases

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to find the minimum height of a tree. I modified my original algorithm for finding the max height of a tree (but this time, just using Math.min instead of Math.max).

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public int minDepth(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null){return Integer.MAX_VALUE;}
        if(root.left == null && root.right == null){return 1;}
        int left = minDepth(root.left);
        int right = minDepth(root.right);
        return Math.min(left, right) + 1;
    }
}
```

It was able to pass a normal tree, and the Integer.MAX_VALUE is there for the test case of

```
2
 \ 
  3
   \
    4
     \
      5
```

However, the code will NOT pass the test case of simply having an empty input "[]".

Is there any changes I can make to this code that will pass? I'm scratching my head and wondering if I should delete it and start from scratch. I feel very close, though.

LC Question: https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-depth-of-binary-tree/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code, is when the tree is skewed for example, it will return the minimum depth-value for subtree's it traversed so far.
if you consider the following tree:

```
2
  \ 
   3
     \
      4
        \
         5
```

it should return `-2147483648`.

carefully check the left and right subtree of root, which is `2`,

```
left subtree depth value: Integer.MAX_VALUE (+1) = -2147483648
right subtree depth value: 4 (+1) = 5
```

now check next element which is `3`,

```
 minimum value found so far: -2147483648
 right subtree depth value: 3 (+1) = 4
```

now check next element which is `4`,

```
 minimum value found so far: -2147483648
 right subtree depth value: 2 (+1) = 3
```

and so on.. and at the end will come up with the minimum number we have found so far, which is `-2147483648` or in case of `2147483647` when the tree is `empty` or `null`.

you need to change the logic in which case it should take minimum depth-value for maximum depth-ed node:

I wrote one solution for you, check if it works:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
public int minDepth(TreeNode root) {
    if(root == null){
        return 0; /* return 0 when the tree is empty */
    }
    /* visit each node in DFS manner, and found maximum depth-ed node possible */
    minDepth(root, 0);
    return min+1;
}

private void minDepth(TreeNode root, int count){
    if(root == null){
        return;
    }else if(root.left == null && root.right == null){
        /* replace the minimum value with maximum-depth node counter */
        if(min > count){
            min = count;
        }
    }else{
        count += 1;
        minDepth(root.left, count);
        minDepth(root.right, count);
    }
```